# Getting the polygon footprint from a map

Tags: image, navmesh

I'm trying to implement the [Explicit Corridors](http://www.cs.uu.nl/docs/vakken/mcrs/papers/3.pdf) method to generate a navmesh for a large city. The algorithm takes a list of convex polygons representing the obstacles as input.

The paper only briefly describes the process of obtaining this "footprint". It looks like all the obstacles are rendered in a texture with an orthographic projection, and then each obstacle is decomposed in convex polygons. They use the CGAL library to do this, but I want do it on my own.

Here's an example of the footprint. Ignore the lines between buildings, but notice how each building (in red) is segmented in convex polygons.

[image]

So what I'm looking for is an algorithm that takes an image as input, and gives me a list of segments representing the contour of each shape.

I checked stuff like Harris corner detection, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it. I also looked at Delaunay triangulation, but this will create a lot of unused segments (the ones you see inside the buildings in the picture above).